# Iterating Through A Vector

Tags: for-loop, iterator

I'm having an issue iterating through a Vector of Objects. I'm using the Iterator interface to cycle through this Vector, but am getting weird errors in my for loop.

I've created my own class QueueExtendingVect that extends Vector and implements Iterator, which is what I'll be using to iterate through the Vector.

For sake of clarity, qev1 and qev2 are QueueExtendingVector instances.

```
qev1 = (QueueExtendingVEctor) qev2.clone(); 
for(Iterator i = qev1.iterator(), int j = 0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
    System.out.println("["+ j + "] = " i.next());
```

I'm getting an error in the for loop header concerning int j = 0, saying "Syntax error on 'int', delete this token". As far as I'm concerned, this should be the correct syntax for a for loop, right?

Comment: This looks like a good place to use a while loop...

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than one variable for your loop and they're of different types, don't declare both of them in the first clause of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax of `for` loop, if you have multiple variables in the first statement (the initialization part), they must be with same type. For example, you can use

```
for (int x=0, y=0; x<5; x++,y++)
```

Otherwise, you have to split them apart. For your case. you should use

```
int j = 0;
for(Iterator i = qev1.iterator(); i.hasNext(); j++) {
```